# What's the difference between a "racist" and a "racially sensitive" remark?

Tags: differences

Former England football captain [John Terry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Terry) has been cleared of making a ***racist*** remark to a fellow professional. However it is clear he said something which caused offence, which the [BBC sports website](http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/0/football/18848273) chose to call ***racially sensitive***.

> In his summation of the case at Westminster Magistrates' Court last
>   Friday, Judge Howard Riddle said that "there is no dispute that John
>   Terry directed [***racially sensitive***] words in the direction of Anton
>   Ferdinand".

So what then is the difference between a "racist" remark and a "racially sensitive" one?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"Racially-insensitive" is the bigot-sensitive version of "racist".

Edit: let me add a bit of less-flippant elaboration:

Usually when someone makes a "racially sensitive" remark, he's being "racially insensitive". A racially sensitive remark is one that touches upon sensitive points, so being insensitive (towards race or any other touchy subject) means not being aware of the sensitivity of the issue.

The reason I call this phrasing "bigot-sensitive" is that it avoids calling someone "racist" by saying he's merely "insensitive to the sensitivity of the issue".

Comment: It's "racially-_sensitive_" not "racially-_insensitive_"

Comment: Are you saying that John Terry should be commended for being "sensitive" in the area of race? I think that's the opposite of what the BBC are saying.

Comment: No, I'm saying that by saying *sensitive remarks*, he was being *insensitive*.

Comment: They weren't _sensitive_ remarks. They were _racially sensitive_. I think we're muddying the waters here.

Comment: @Urbycoz, Avner is saying (or implying) several things: first, that "racially sensitive" is a euphemism for "racially insensitive".  Second, that either of those is a euphemism for "racist".  Third, that "A racially sensitive remark is one that touches upon sensitive points".  Obviously, he could phrase all this much better.

Comment: @jwpat7,Urbycoz: I don't see any problems with Avner's phrasing here. He's talking about fine distinctions, *and* showing how they can be differently perceived from different perspectives. Quite lucidly, imho.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, you seem to imply I found fault with Avner's phrasing, but I did no such thing, and even said he could phrase it better than I did.  But now that you mention it, his answer could be better-organized.  Also he should delete some of his now-superfluous comments.

Comment: @jwpat7: oic. Yes, I think I misunderstood your comment - you presumably meant *"he could **(and in fact did)** phrase all this much better **than I**"*, but I read it as *"he **could** phrase all this much better **than he actually did**"*.

Comment: @jwpat7 So "_racially sensitive_ is a euphemism for _racially insensitive_". I'm sorry, but that just doesn't seem right to me. Surely they are diametrically opposite. Am I the only one who's thinking this?

Comment: They're not really euphemisms, but two sides of the same coin, and some confusion in the original text. A *racially insensitive* comment is one that touches on *racially sensitive* issues. So when someone refers to a *racially sensitive comment*, it means in *this* specific context, "a comment that touches on racially sensitive issues", with the implication that it did so in an insensitive manner.

Comment: @Avner Shahar-Kashtan Ok, I can see what you are getting at now. I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 6):

In this case, a racist remark is one where insult is meant by saying the words. A racially sensitive remark is one that uses words that could be insulting or abusive, but depending on the context.

Note the square brackets indicating omission and/or insertion. The BBC are tip-toeing around the words Judge Howard Riddle used in his summation by removing them and replacing them with a watered-down summary.

The judge actually wrote in his judgment ([PDF](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/shared/bsp/hi/pdfs/13_07_12_r_v_john_terry.pdf) linked from the article):

> There  is  also  no  dispute  that  John  Terry  directed  the  words  “black cunt” in the direction of Anton Ferdinand.

It's not the BBC's place to use the word *racist* as they would then be making a judgment of guilt about John Terry. In fact, the judge also said:

> ... the issue for this court to decide is not whether Mr Terry is a racist, in the broadest sense of the word... The issue between the defendant and the Crown is whether Mr Terry uttered the words “fucking black cunt” by way of insult. If he did then the offence is made out, regardless of what may have motivated him.

Additionally, the court reached a not guilt verdict. The judge wrote of Terry:

> It is therefore possible that what he said was not intended as an insult, but rather as a challenge to what he believed had been said to him.
>
> In those circumstances, there being a doubt, the only verdict the court can
> record is one of not guilty.

Instead, like most news sources, the BBC don't want to publish the words directly in their article (but have no problem publishing the judgment document which repeats them many times), and have referred to them obliquely.

Comment: John Terry. A proper gentleman.

Answer (score 3):

I can explain the distinction best with an example:

Some years ago there was a local news story of a mall Santa who was fired for calling a little black boy a monkey. He was accused of racism.  The issue with this is... people call small children monkeys all the time. They’re loud and climb on things and generally mischievous and chaotic... i.e. monkeys.  I don’t doubt this man called lots of kids monkeys. He was (I believe) simply trying to be silly and joke with the kid a bit.  (And yes, I call my own daughter “monkey” fairly often.  We’re white.)

But there is a definite history of black people in America being called monkeys, apes and so forth as a racist insult. The mall Santa probably should have been aware of this and avoided this particular joke.  So his comment was not *racist*, in that he did not think of it, nor intend it, as a racial slur; but it was racially sensitive because of the ugly history of the word and similar being used as a slur.

Racially sensitive = you may not be racist, but you still should have realized that would be seen as offensive

Answer (score 2):

The word "sensitive" in the phrase "racially sensitive" means "touchy."

> [sensitive](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sensitive) = calling for tact, care, or caution in treatment

The difference between "a racist remark" and "racially sensitive words" is that "racist" can mean a conscious, deliberate, and unrepentant act of insulting.

The expression "racially sensitive," on the other hand, is open to the interpretation and possibility that “what was said was not intended as an insult.”

Comment: So "John Terry directed [touchy] words in the direction of Anton Ferdinand".

Answer (score 1):

When I hear "Racist remark", I imagine a remark that places a person's ethnicity as the cause of their failing, or in some way contributing to their inadequacy, or part of a verbal attack because of their race.

"Racially sensitive remark" makes me think it was a word that, in itself, is not a direct insult towards a person. For example, the word "nigger" is considered racially sensitive because of the history around the word, not necessarily because it confers any meaning (aside from that the person is black).

Comment: I believe the word he said was "black", and that he also said himself that it was the only word in the sentence that was _not_ offensive.

Comment: I disagree: the N-word is racist. Period. The words you would use to explain your use of the n-word are probably racially insensitive.